# Rotate a set of points in Tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman, feynman

I am trying to draw some Feynman diagrams using TikZ. An object I need to use several times is the one in the picture below. But depending on the case I'd like to present it in one of the two ways in the picture (either as an "x" or as a "cross")

[image]

I've drawn the x version as follows. I know I could draw the cross version in the same way changing all the coordinates by hand but I was wondering if there was a way to rotate all the coordinates 45° to do it automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.1.0}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,automata,backgrounds,calc,er,patterns,positioning,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

        \coordinate (A1) at (-1,2);
        \coordinate (A2) at (0,1);
        \coordinate (A3) at (1,2);
        \coordinate (A4) at (2,1);
        \coordinate (A5) at (1,0);
        \coordinate (A6) at (2,-1);
        \coordinate (A7) at (1,-2);
        \coordinate (A8) at (0,-1);
        \coordinate (A9) at (-1,-2);
        \coordinate (A10) at (-2,-1);
        \coordinate (A11) at (-1,0);
        \coordinate (A12) at (-2,1);
        
        \draw (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3);
        \draw (A4) -- (A5) -- (A6);
        \draw (A7) -- (A8) -- (A9);
        \draw (A10) -- (A11) -- (A12);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Edit: Regarding the sugestions of adding [rotate=45], that does indeed work when only one of the "x" is present. I should have mentioned that some of the diagrams I want to draw has two "x" side by side. In that case adding [rotate=45] makes it so they are not side by side, but one them is diagonaly above the other.

Comment: Just add [`rotate=45`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-transformations#pgf./tikz/rotate) as an [option to the TikZ picture](https://tikz.dev/tikz-scopes#pgf.tikzpicture)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is working (3 adjacent cross):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \an in {0,90,180,270}
            \draw[rotate=\an] (2,-1)--(1,0)--(2,1);
        
        \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm,red,rotate=45]
            \foreach \an in {0,90,180,270}
                \draw[rotate=\an] (2,-1)--(1,0)--(2,1);
        \end{scope}
        
        \begin{scope}[xshift=10cm,blue,rotate=30]
            \foreach \an in {0,90,180,270}
            \draw[rotate=\an] (2,-1)--(1,0)--(2,1);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

**ADD**: A new simple version that define a newcommand (`\cross`) inside a `scope` environment with 4 parameters:

#1 : xshift for the `\cross` (in cm);    #2 : the color;    #3 : the rotation angle (in degree);    #4 : the scale factor for adapting the cross to complete picture.

The code (with 2 examples of crosses):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\newcommand*{\cross}[4]{
\begin{scope}[xshift=#1cm,#2,rotate=#3,scale=#4]
    \foreach \an in {0,90,180,270}
    \draw[rotate=\an] (2,-1)--(1,0)--(2,1);
\end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \cross{5}{blue}{0}{1}
        \cross{0}{red}{45}{.5}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: I just tried it, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: @dorrel It works. See the picture that I have added.

Comment: I obtain that output both with, or without the [rotate=45]. Without the [rotate=45] do you obtain the cross one?

Comment: @dorrel No! I dont know why. I use this method for pictures more and more complex and it works well. I need to investigate.

Comment: @dorrel See my updated answer. Now You can draw crosses at any angle... starting from only 3 base points!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem once, the easy solution is no use `coordinate` command with transformations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.1.0}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,automata,backgrounds,calc,er,patterns,positioning,quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \coordinate (A1) at (-1,2);
        \coordinate (A2) at (0,1);
        \coordinate (A3) at (1,2);
        \coordinate (A4) at (2,1);
        \coordinate (A5) at (1,0);
        \coordinate (A6) at (2,-1);
        \coordinate (A7) at (1,-2);
        \coordinate (A8) at (0,-1);
        \coordinate (A9) at (-1,-2);
        \coordinate (A10) at (-2,-1);
        \coordinate (A11) at (-1,0);
        \coordinate (A12) at (-2,1);

\begin{scope}[rotate=40]
            \draw (-1,2)--(0,1)-- (1,2);
        \draw (2,1) -- (1,0)-- (2,-1);
        \draw  (1,-2) -- (0,-1) --  (-1,-2);
        \draw  (-2,-1) --  (-1,0) -- (-2,1);
\end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    
\end{document}
```