# It is possible to integrate this pattern new command in the standard pattern procedure with a special name?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern

I answered to this question [Rotate a set of points in Tikz figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/702952/rotate-a-set-of-points-in-tikz-figure/702953#702953) with a new command that I extended to create new patterns.
This is the code with some example of pattern created:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\newcommand*{\cross}[5]{
    \begin{scope}[xshift=#1cm,
        yshift=#2cm,
        #3, %color
        rotate=#4,
        scale=#5]
        \foreach \an in {0,90,180,270}
        \draw [rotate=\an] (2,-1)--(1,0)--(2,1);
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \cross{5}{0}{}{0}{1}
        \cross{5}{2}{}{0}{1}
        \cross{7}{0}{}{0}{1}
        \cross{7}{2}{}{0}{1}
        \cross{9}{0}{}{0}{1}
        \cross{9}{2}{}{0}{1}
    \end{tikzpicture}\qquad
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3]
        \clip[draw] (5,5) circle(5.5);
        \foreach \x in {0,2,...,10}{%
            \foreach \y in {0,2,...,10}{%
        \cross{\x}{\y}{blue}{0}{.5}
    }}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \vspace{1cm}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4]
        \clip[draw] (5,5) circle(5.5 and 3);
        \foreach \x in {0,2,...,10}{%
            \foreach \y in {0,2,...,10}{%
                \cross{\x}{\y}{red}{0}{.8}
        }}
    \end{tikzpicture}\qquad
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
        \clip[draw] (.5,.5) rectangle (9.5,9.5);
        \foreach \x in {0,1.17,...,10}{%
            \foreach \y in {0,1.17,...,10}{%
                \cross{\x}{\y}{}{0}{.3}
        }}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

My question is: It is possible to integrate this patterns in the defaults patterns accessible with the pattern library of tikz?